# Addition of getJSON request results

Tags: getjson

I am beginner with getJSON and JS programming. I tried the answers I found on this forum but still got a NaN instead of the expected result ( 4950) of 2475 + 2475. What am doing wrong?

Here is the output generated from the getJSON request on apache solr

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">114</int>
            <lst name="params">
               <str name="q">objectType:mods AND objectProject:DESerie AND state:published</str>
               <str name="_">1568794672289</str>
            </lst>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="2475" start="0" maxScore="2.1764848"> </result>

</response>
```

This is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON('../api/v1/search?q=objectType:mods AND objectProject:DESerie AND state:published&amp;wt=json', function (data) {
var var1 = $('#series').text(data.response.numFound);
var intVar1 = parseInt(var1, 10);
var total = intVar1 + intVar1;
$('#total').text(total);
```

Here is my display code

```
<div id="pubtyp">
    Series: <span id="total"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you suppose `var var1 = $('#series').text(data.response.numFound);` does? There doesn't seem to be an element with id "series"? Also `text()` doesn't take arguments.

Comment: .. and since `var1` is undefined,  `var intVar1 = parseInt(var1, 10);` ands up being `NaN`